# Как узнать что превышено время ответа?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, время

Есть бот VK на Python (вот фрагмент):

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.peer_id == ID_GROUP and (INPUT_TEXT_FINALE in str(event.text)): #условие2
                      <код>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы если время после последнего выполнения условия2 было больше 10 секунд,т.е. на сообщение нет ответа, то выполнялся код.

Пытался реализовать с помощью time.time()

```
time2 = 0
for event in longpoll.listen():
    time1 = time.time()
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if time1-time2>10 and time1-time2!=time1:
             <код>
        if event.peer_id == ID_GROUP and (INPUT_TEXT_FINALE in str(event.text)):
             time2 = time.time()
             <код>
```

Но он срабатывает редко...

Надеюсь понятно изъяснил проблему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что метод `longpoll.listen()` - просто цикл `while True`. Вот [код этого метода](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/vk_api/longpoll.html#VkLongPoll.listen).

Наивный вариант решения проблемы - вынести цикл `for event in longpoll.listen()` в отдельную функцию и убивать ее через 10 секунд, если нет ответа. Это можно сделать, используя модуль `multiprocessing`. Вот его документация: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

При этом нужно понимать, что функция будет запускаться в отдельном процессе, поэтому передача аргументов должна быть реализована средством модуля `multiprocessing`. Глобальные переменные вашей программы **не будут** доступны из этой функции.

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:

Вот минимальный вариант кода:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from time import sleep


def example_function(got_response):
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        # Сохраняем информацию о том, что ответ получен
        got_response.value = 1

        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            # условие2
            if event.peer_id == ID_GROUP and (INPUT_TEXT_FINALE in str(event.text)):
                # <код>


if __name__ == '__main__':
    got_response = Value('i', 0)

    p = Process(target=example_function, args=(got_response,))
    p.start()

    sleep(10)

    if got_response.value:
        print('Ответ был получен!')
        print('Функция продолжит работу...')
    else:
        print('Ответ не был получен за 10 секунд')
        print('Убиваю функцию...')
        p.terminate()
        print('Функция убита!')

    p.join()
```

Comment: Извините, не можете помочь с кодом? Я плох в программировании)

Comment: @Setaz213, я добавил код в ответ. Надеюсь, что правильно понял логику вашей программы и поставил `got_response.value = 1` в нужное место. Информация о передаче аргументов есть в документации (ссылка в моем ответе на вопрос)

Comment: Место немного не то, но смысл я понял... Большое спасибо)